# Create URL aliases for Entityform submissions

Tags: 7, uri, entities

I have the [**Entityform**](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityform) module installed on a Drupal 7 portal and I've created a new entityform type (let's call it "Preview").

When I land on the list of "Preview" submissions, each submission View link points to `[host]/[drupal_base]/entityform/[entityform_id]`

What I'd like to get is to change "entityform" term in that url path with something like "preview" term, so that I'll have `[host]/[drupal_base]/preview/[entityform_id]`

I tried to define a URL alias from the admin configuration panel, but from what I've understood, I can't define an alias with a dynamic `[entityform_id]` (maybe using a kind of placeholder). Am I wrong about this?

I'm not so skilled in Drupal, so I wonder if there's a way to achieve that result?

Answer (score 1):

*Note: This answer only applies specifically for the input form (I misunderstood the question above)*

I was able to accomplish this by using simply modifying the entityform made configuration.

- Go to /admin/structure/entityform_types
- Click on the *edit* link for the entity form you wish to change
- Scroll to the bottom and in the *URL path settings* set the specific custom paths that you wish
- Save

It's that easy and it works for both the preview and the actual form :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that path works for accessing the "form page". I'd like to override the submission View link

Comment: Ahhh shoot sorry I understand now! Your right the only thing that I can suggest is to you log a bug since that has not been added to the functionality sorry for misunderstanding

Comment: hey no problem mate, thanks a lot for your effort ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically create URL aliases for Entityform Type submissions by using the contributed [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) and [Pathauto Entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto_entity) modules.

Here's how:

1. Download, install and enable the **Pathauto** and **Pathauto Entity** modules (if they aren't already)
2. Within Pathauto, enable the *Entityform Submission* entity type at:

   Administration > Configuration > Search and Metadata > URL Aliases > Entities
   `admin/config/search/path/entities`

   [image: Pathauto Entity]
3. Create a new default Pathauto pattern for Entityform Submissions using the following replacement patterns:

   `[entityform:type:label]/[entityform:entityform-id]`

   > *The `[entityform:type:label]` token is the **key ingredient** and corresponds to the Entityform Type's name or label (e.g. "Preview") and will be lowercased and hyphenated in the alias (e.g. `/preview/1234`).*

   [image: Pathauto Entityform Submission Pattern]
4. Save the Pathauto configuration

Once this is complete, all new Entityform Type submissions will no longer use the default path registered by the Entityform module (i.e. `/entityform/1234`) and instead use the new alias pattern we defined (i.e. `/preview/1234`).

You can use the "Bulk Update" feature in Pathauto to add/update/delete any pre-existing Entityform Submissions aliases.

Answer (score 0):

[Pathauto_entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto_entity)

> You can select the entities to be enabled in Home » Administration »
>   Configuration » Search and metadata » URL aliases » Entities tab, and
>   they will appear in Home » Administration » Configuration » Search and
>   metadata » Patterns, where you can define the desired aliases for
>   them.
>
> Make sure to define those patterns before trying to create new URL
>   aliases (including bulk update), as otherwise they won't be created.
>
> If the Entities tab does not appear, it means that the site has no
>   custom entities defined, apart from the standard content types,
>   taxonomies, comments and users.